# Creating an array of server IPs in the Logstash configuration?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack

I wanted to know if it’s possible to create an array of my server’s IP addresses to make the Logstash config file a bit easier to edit and read. I’m tagging our CentOS boxes with “linux”, and our ASAs with “networking”. Right now, the filter part of my config looks something like this:

```
filter {
    if [host] == “10.x.x.1” or [host] == “10.x.x.2” or … or [host] “10.x.x.30” {
        mutate {
            add_tag => “linux”
        }
    }

    if [host] == “10.x.x.200” or [host] == “10.x.x.201” or … or [host] “10.x.x.250” {
        mutate {
            add_tag => “networking”
        }
}
```

This works, but since I have 30+ nodes in each category, the line is extremely long. I was thinking of doing something like this instead (in pseudocode):

```
array [linux_hosts] = [“10.x.x.1”,
                       “10.x.x.2”,
                       “10.x.x.3”]

if [host] in [linux_hosts] {
    mutate {
        add_tag => “linux”
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How are you shipping the logs to logstash?

Comment: I’m using rsyslog to forward the logs from my CentOS boxes, and I’m using the built-in syslog forwarding feature on the ASAs. I’m using the TCP and UDP (both listening on port 514) input plugins in Logstash because the Syslog input plugin seems to create grok parsing errors. Let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Comment: If you had been shipping with something like logstash or logstash-forwarder, you could set these fields on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your other constraints, I'd say that translate{} might be the best option.  Not great, but perhaps best...

```
translate {
    dictionary => [
        "10.1.1.1",   "linux",
        "10.1.1.200", "networking"
    ],
    destination => "source_type"
}
```

You can also read the dictionary from a file, if that helps.